# Python nested loops do not continue with the subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested, subprocess

I tried to run below code but it just loops in the very inner one and then stops, I do not understand why it doesn't continue to the outer loops?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                                                                                                                                               

import os
import sys
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen([find...],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for i in range(...):
        p2 = subprocess.Popen([grep...],stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        for e in range(...):
               p3=subprocess.Popen([grep...],stdin=p2.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
               for file in p3.stdout:
                        print(str(i)+str(e)+str(file))
```

Comment: stop? or blocks?

Comment: you should call `p3.wait()` in the end (same for the others)

Comment: Just stops after the first element `e in range(...)`,  `p3.wait()` doesn't work!

Comment: there's a conceptual issue in this triple loop: first p2 grep process consumes all output of find. I would create a list of files to grep into, then grep. This can be written using pure python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the concept is wrong

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen([find...],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for i in range(...):
        p2 = subprocess.Popen([grep...],stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

when running this code (first iteration), `p1.stdout` is consumed fully by `p2`. So next spawns of `p2` get an empty output.

(same goes for the inner loop)

I would write that in pure python.

First loop to match the files you want to grep on:

```
files_to_process = []
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(start_directory):
    files_to_process += [f for f in files if <some condition> ]
```

Once you have the list of files, you can open them in a lot of loops and search their content. I would advise to avoid `grep` and do something like:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    contents = f.read()
    results = re.search(regexp,contents)
```

(or line by line)